# In String If There's backslash how can I change it to regular slash

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want Doing a code in it I'm Taking Path from user  in python now in that path I want to replace `'\'` to `'/'`
I used re but it is traceback tell me What I can do

```
import os,re
address = input("Enter Path You of the Folder Which Contains files")


check=re.compile('\\')
if check.match(address):
    for char in address:
        if char == '\\':
            char.replace(char,'/')

print(address)
```

I used os for other reason

Comment: `address = address.replace('\\', '/')`

Comment: `replace` can used with the complete string. In your code you are replacing `'\\'` for a different variable named `char` and not for the variable `address`. So, you're not seeing the expected output. The correct code would be `address.replace('\', '/')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

address.replace('\\','/')
it will work for all '\\' present in the string.